# Using next-themes for dark mode generates hydration failed error

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, darkmode

I am trying to implement a dark mode using **next-themes**. Inside the `layout.tsx` file, `<body>` contains a background color. Hence, I need to wrap the whole `<body>` inside `<ThemeProvider>` to change the background as well when toggling to dark mode. I am importing the `<ThemeProvider>` from `./lib/providers.ts` as a client component to avoid making the whole app a client component.

`providers.ts` file as follows:

```js
"use client";

export { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
```

while the `layout.tsx` file is as follows:

```js
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Nunito_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/lib/providers";

const nunito_sans = Nunito_Sans({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My name | Portfolio",
  description: "My moto",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <ThemeProvider>
        <body
          className={`${nunito_sans.className} bg-gradient-to-r from-green to to-blue-400`}
        >
          <main className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6 my-14 px-5 lg:px-48 sm:px-20 md:px-32">
            <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 bg-white rounded-2xl p-4 text-center">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-9 bg-white rounded-2xl flex flex-col overflow-hidden">
              <Navbar />
              {children}
            </div>
          </main>
        </body>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, it throughs an error:

| ❌ Error |
| --- |
| Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. |

| ⚠️ Warning |
| --- |
| Expected server HTML to contain a matching in . |

I have also tried creating a separate component `<Provider>` and wrapping the `body` inside it but, the same warning occurs:

```js
"use client";

import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

export default function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
}
```

Comment: **the problem come from how to use** <html lang="en"> and <body ...> **please check an example of next-themes** https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes/tree/main/examples/example **and check How to add a class to the body tag in Next.js** https://smnh.me/add-class-to-body-tag-in-nextjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `layout.tsx`, remove `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

If you have a need for `<head>` tag, use the component `<Head>` from Next.js like:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
```

So your `layout.tsx` becomes:

```
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Nunito_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/lib/providers";

const nunito_sans = Nunito_Sans({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My name | Portfolio",
  description: "My moto",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <main className={`${nunito_sans.className} bg-gradient-to-r from-green to to-blue-400 grid grid-cols-12 gap-6 my-14 px-5 lg:px-48 sm:px-20 md:px-32`}>
        <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 bg-white rounded-2xl p-4 text-center">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-9 bg-white rounded-2xl flex flex-col overflow-hidden">
          <Navbar />
          {children}
        </div>
      </main>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

You also need to verify that within `Sidebar` and `Navbar` components, you have only valid html according to W3C (failing which you shall hydration error from Next.js).

Answer (score 0):

Within your layout.tsx add the suppressHydrationWarning

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) 

{
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body>
          <ThemeProviders>
            {children
          </ThemeProviders>
          
        </body>
    </html>
  );
```